# Calculate intra-class correlation (or some other measure of reliability) with variable number of raters

Tags: r, python, intraclass-correlation

I have some stimuli rated by users. I want to estimate how much of the variance in ratings is due to the stimuli, so that I can compare between various types of ratings which are the most reliable. This seems like it is an Intra-Class Correlation (ICC(1,1): one-way random effects), but my problem is that packages to do this in R (psych) or python (pingouin) all assume that the ratings come from the same set of raters, while in my data every single rating was made by a different individual and the number of ratings per stimuli varies between 3 and 5,000.

My dataset looks like:

```
STIMULI       RATINGS_FEATURE1
A             [1,3,2,1,3]
B             [4,3]
C             [6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,5,4,1,8,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]
D             [3,2,3,3,1]
....
```

What do I want to do?

Comment: you said that you want to "compare between various types of ratings", but you only gave a description about one rating type. What are the other types? What other data do you have available?

Answer (score 2):

Correlation is a statistic that relates to *paired* measurements. Intraclass correlation is a generalisation that extends the pairs to groups.

> while in my data every single rating was made by a different individual

If you don't have grouped data, then correlation makes no sense.

> I want to estimate how much of the variance in ratings is due to the stimuli,

This sounds more like ANOVA or a Kruskal–Wallis test.

Comment: ICC is based on the premise of an equal number of graders per item/subject above. I think the question asks what to do if there are different number of graders per item.

Comment: @user321627 "while in my data every single rating was made by a different individual". In the case of just a sparse dataset but at least some repeated measurements by the same individual, then I believe a random effects model could do the trick. I remember having seen such question before.

Comment: That question is: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570103/

Comment: How would one go from a random effects model to the ICC?

Comment: @user321627 *"Beginning with Ronald Fisher, the intraclass correlation has been regarded within the framework of analysis of variance (ANOVA), and more recently in the framework of random effects models. A number of ICC estimators have been proposed. Most of the estimators can be defined in terms of the random effects model "* from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation). I am not an expert in this and do not know what the standard expressions and statistics are, but intuitively it seems all like a special case of anova with repeated measures or random effects.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've collected your data precludes any calculation of 'reliability'. The first part of your question asks:

> ...how much of the variance in ratings is due to the stimuli, ...

You can answer this with a standard mixed effect model i.e.,

Ratings ~ 1 + (1|Stimuli)

Using this framework you could estimate the total *repeatability* across all stimuli. See for example the [rptR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rptR/vignettes/rptR.html).

**Edit**

To expand on my answer, take example data from the rptR package. Your data is unbalanced, so we'll create a new unbalanced data set from the example data.

```
library(rptR)
library(lme4)
data(BeetlesBody)

set.seed(12345)
BeetlesBody_unbalanced = BeetlesBody[sample(c(1:960),1000,replace = T),]
table(BeetlesBody_unbalanced $Population)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
106  80  87  83  73  71  65  92  93  79  87  84
```

We can compute the repeatability as follows:

```
rpt(BodyL ~  (1 | Population), grname = "Population", data = BeetlesBody, datatype = "Gaussian", 
+     nboot = 0, npermut = 0)


Repeatability estimation using the lmm method 

Repeatability for Population
R  = 0.299
SE =  NA 
CI = [NA, NA]
P  = 8.08e-62 [LRT]
     NA [Permutation]
```

Our repeatability is 0.299. Note that repeatability is just a ratio composed of the random effects variances. See the [rptR package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rptR/vignettes/rptR.html) for more on this. Things get more complicated if your model includes fixed effects and you want to account for the variance explained in your calculation of repeatability.

```
summary(lmer(BodyL ~ 1 + (1 | Population),data = BeetlesBody))

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: BodyL ~ 1 + (1 | Population)
   Data: BeetlesBody

REML criterion at convergence: 3893.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2950 -0.7770  0.0186  0.7867  2.6107 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Population (Intercept) 1.377    1.173   
 Residual               3.235    1.798   
Number of obs: 960, groups:  Population, 12

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  14.0827     0.3436   40.98
```

That is, repeatability = 1.377/(1.377+3.235) = 0.299

Comment: The issue with the package above is that it requires there to be the same number of raters per subject. Do you know if theres a workaround?

Comment: I haven't encountered that problem with that package. Have you tried turning off the options for bootstrapped-CIs and permutation-based p-values?

Comment: I expanded my answer to show an example.