# Computing ICCs in Matlab, to assess rater consistency (inter-rater agreement)

Tags: intraclass-correlation, psychology, rating

In an experiment, participants rated each of several musical stimuli on 5 aspects (ratings A to E), across ~3,000 trials. Stimuli were performed (by a previous set of subjects) either solo or duo (ensemble size), and were learned under 3 different learning conditions. Thus, the ratings, ensemble size and the learning conditions are all within-subjects.

The screenshot below shows the data structure, for clarity:

[image]

The ultimate question of the study is whether any of the 5 ratings can predict ensemble size. But as a secondary question, I'd also like to assess how consistent the participants' scores are to each other, for each of the 5 ratings, separately for the two ensemble sizes (1 and 2, i.e. SOLO and DUO).  For this, I figured I'd use intra-class correlations (ICCs).

I might be wrong, but I take 'consistency' to mean inter-rater agreement (inter-rater reliability), which in turn probably amounts to something like spread or variance.

From reading about the various types of ICC (refs below), and from other papers that had similar data structures ([example](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17470218.2013.863954?casa_token=MLf6SoJbRbcAAAAA:HvyQiHEGQTFn9bniWHjoijoxZeLHY_Z68Wh3Yt4MnwjIxD14_YtPU6J-RdcNiL3atGI5HLXn5kpPkb4)), I inferred that it's the `ICC(2,k)` form that I need.

I found a Matlab [function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22099) that computes ICCs but it's not at all clear to me how I need to arrange the input arguments. Other Matlab functions for this are incomplete, or are meant for other types of ICC.

Could anyone please suggest:

1. how I can compute ICC(2,k) in this case, ideally in Matlab;
2. whether it makes sense (in the spirit of an ICC-derived consistency measure) to define "groups" as any of the levels of my manipulations: ensemble size (1 or 2), question number (A to E), and learning condition (1 to 3).

---

A brief theoretical addon to my question. I know that, since ICCs give a composite of intra-observer and inter-observer variability, their results are difficult to interpret when observers are not exchangeable/interchangeable, in which case alternative measures such as Cohen's kappa are more suitable measures of agreement. Can I assume my participants to be interchangeable in this case, or on what would the answer to this question depend?

---

REFERENCES:

1. McGraw, K. O., & Wong, S. P. (1996). Forming inferences about some intraclass correlation coefficients. Psychological Methods, 1(1), 30.
2. Shrout, P. E., & Fleiss, J. L. (1979). Intraclass correlations: Uses in assessing rater reliability. Psychological Bulletin, 86(2), 420.
3. Koo, T. K., & Li, M. Y. (2016). A Guideline of Selecting and Reporting Intraclass Correlation Coefficients for Reliability Research. Journal of Chiropractic Medicine, 15(2), 155–163.

Comment: *"I'd also like to assess how consistent the participants' scores are to each other, for each of the 5 ratings"* By *participants* you mean the raters? Do different raters get the same performer and conditions? (or do different raters get the same performer but with different conditions?)

Comment: Sorry, this was indeed a bit confusing. It's the second alternative: different raters get the same performer but with different conditions. The participants in this study only did rating, the performing was done by a different (previous) group, who recorded the stimuli.

Comment: I computed the (C-k) and (C-1) types - using the function's own notation now. In both cases I obtained r values >.9, which makes sense given my data; but p-values of exactly 0, which is strange.

Comment: I'd have also liked to compute the (3,k) type, "Two-way mixed effects, consistency, multiple raters/measurements" according to the Koo and Li paper. But it's unclear which input argument that corresponds to in that function, since the documentation gives both a case 2 and a case 3 for a single type value...

Comment: Cohens Kappa is good for interrater agreement.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned at the end of my question. Could you ellaborate on which of the two is more suitable given the "interchangeable" thing?